# npm workspaces: update workspace package.json's embedded in package-lock.json

Tags: npm, monorepo, package-lock.json

I am using npm workspaces to manage a monorepo. I've noticed that the top-level `package-lock.json` includes a cached copy of each workspace's `package.json`, in its `"package"` field. How can I refresh these cached copies without also updating all dependency versions in `package-lock.json`?

So far, the best approach I've found is:

- Delete the top-level `package-lock.json`.
- Run `npm i`.

This works, but also updates all dependency versions in `package-lock.json`. I would prefer to avoid that, in case updating a dependency breaks something, and because this creates enormous git diffs for `package-lock.json`.

#### Non-solutions

Running `npm update <workspace package name>` does not work, at least if I have changed a workspace's package version number (`No matching version found for <package name>@<new version>`).

Same issue if I try `npm i --package-lock-only` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114661/update-version-number-in-package-json-and-package-lock-json-without-updating-dep).

#### Motivation

`package-lock.json` is checked into my git monorepo, so I presume I need to update it like this each time I bump the workspace packages' versions.

I've also experienced a problem in the past where I updated the `bin` field in a workspace's `package.json`, but `npm ci` kept using the old version. That was fixed by refreshing `package-lock.json`, but again at the cost of updating all dependency versions.

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own script for e.g.:

get the workspaces:

```bash
WORKSPACES=`jq  -r '.workspaces | @sh' package.json | tr -d \\'`
```

then run a bash for loop:

```bash
for w in ${WORKSPACES[@]};  do echo \"$w\" && pushd . && cd $w && npm i && rm -rf node_modules; popd; done;"
```

so in pacakge.json you could combinging in a script:

```json
"update": "WORKSPACES=`jq  -r '.workspaces | @sh' package.json | tr -d \\'` && for w in ${WORKSPACES[@]};  do echo \"$w\" && pushd . && cd $w && npm i && rm -rf node_modules; popd; done;"
```

or something like that.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [npm version](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-version) command to update the version in both `package.json` and `package-lock.json`

```bash
npm version <version> --workspace=<package-name>
```